# How can i check the value of let i = index in ngIf directive

Tags: angular

I have a for loop.

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products;let i =index">
   <div *ngIf="'i' != 3>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am checking the value of i in my ngIf,so to show or to now show something.
But it does not work.I have a third index in my products array but it does not work.
Where is my mistake?

I tried also

```
<div *ngIf="i != 3">
   </div>
```

But without success

Comment: You should define the *ngIf in the below standard format.
**<div *ngIf='i!=3'></div>**

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to put 'i' in string conotations in the *ngIf directive.

also you should use **double equals** : **!==** and not **!=**.

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products;let i =index">
   <div *ngIf="i !== 3">
   </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
Also you should consider using `<ng-container>` for such procedures, to have a clear sepearation of concerns for semantics.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of products;let i =index">
   <div *ngIf="i !== 3">
     this is product {{i}}
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: @secretusername123 how about using an other index ? will it work then ? also arrays start at 0. And you should always use tripple equals or double equals in negated statments. 
Hav you tried using a <ng-container> for the *ngFor directive instead of a div ?

Comment: Why should i use ng-container instead div for ngFor Sir ?

Comment: divs are semantical indikators for layout in the html. If you want to repeat a value with a certain semantic, you should use container that do not interact with the layout of the HTML. a seperation of concerns is also usefull to seperate logic form the UI elements. Give it a try, if it does not work, maybe your Array is not properly initialized, for whatever reason.